# RewriteRule not work properly on SSL redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I want to use SSL in my site, on all pages except one folder and a homepage.
I'm using Joomla as CMS. My home page URI are ( "/" , "index.php" ) and a folder that does not use SSL is "enamad". I wrote this line in .htaccess file. But when I click to menu item, it redirects to https://domain.com/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/enamad 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For example in menu I have a item with this link:

http://domain.com/buy

which I want to redirect to https (https://domain.com/buy). But when I click on (http://domain.com/buy) Apache redirects to (https://domain.com/index.php)

.htaccess

```
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(enamad|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal only joomla default .htaccess.no another SSL rule

Comment: @anubhava : "enamad" is a directory. .htaccess in root(public_html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(enamad|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

i.e. using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` which doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: Make sure this is very first rule and you test in a new browser. Also where is this htaccess located?

Comment: i placed htaccess on post.

Comment: Oh that is happening because you have kept my suggested rule at bottom. Keep it **just after** first `RewriteEngine On` line and retest in a new browser.